# $Y = \frac { K A ^ { 3 } } { ( B + D ) ( C - D ) }$

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

K is a constant

Find an expression to approximately determine the variance of Y, assuming $A , B , C ,$ and $D$ are probabilistically independent.

isnt the expression they have already given me the expression that determines the variance of Y

Answer (score 0):

Your $Y$ is undefined when $C-D = 0$, and "blows up" as $C-D \to 0$.  The variance won't exist if, e.g., $C-D$ has a density that approaches a nonzero constant at $0$.
In order for it to exist you'll want to assume $C$ and $D$ are supported in disjoint intervals.  Similarly for $B$ and $-D$.